# How to pass list to aws CDK bootstrap `--cloudformation-execution-policies` parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell, aws-cdk

## Goal

To use AWS CDK `bootstrap` command in powershell, using the `--cloudformation-execution-policies` argument with a list.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html) does not have specific examples for OSs.

### Tests

- Passing a single string worked fine, eg: `--cloudformation-execution-policies "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess"`
- Passing a list of strings in various ways does not work
- `--cloudformation-execution-policies "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess"`
- `--cloudformation-execution-policies "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess" "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess"`
- `--cloudformation-execution-policies @("arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess")`
- `--cloudformation-execution-policies @('arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess','arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess')`

They all fail with:

```
 ARN arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess is not valid.
Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput;
```

#### Environment

- OS:
- Python: Python 3.9.5
- AWS CLI: aws-cli/2.2.5 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
- Node: v13.14.0
- CDK: 1.116.0 (build d04661d)

#### Question

Which is the correct way CDK tool parses lists in powershell?

Comment: Doc update [merged](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cdk-guide/pull/351), hopefully it gets released soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## References

- CDK template `CloudFormationExecutionPolicies` parameter [info link](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/f66f4b80da22b4d24d4419acc3984b56d5690b2e/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-template.yaml#L18)
- CFN template Parameter `CommaDelimitedList` type [info link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)

### Answer

The key is that CDK uses a CFN parameter to pass the value, and being a `CommaDelimitedList`, the way to pass it is as a single string, rather than a list

ie: `--cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess,arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess'`